# this.nav.getActiveChildNav(...).select is not a function

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I am developing an app using ionic 3.

My side menu has a homepage and the upon opening the tab it will by default land to homepage.I have one button on homepage on click of that it will go to tabs page. I have implemented that using superlabs, Everything is working nice. Except from tabspage, When I click on home which is in side menu ,I get the following error:

> this.nav.getActiveChildNav(...).select is not a function

**UPDATE**
I am using https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs to create tabs

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-medicinesreminder',
  templateUrl: 'medicinesreminder.html',
})
export class MedicinesreminderPage {
  tab1Root = "PresentPage";
  tab2Root = "MissedPage";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.navCtrl.getAllChildNavs();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MedicinesreminderPage');
  }

}

<super-tabs  indicatorColor="indicator" toolbarColor="white" toolbarBackground="tabbar">
  <super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="Present"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="Missing"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: show your code for importing section. Shall i tell some code example for you.

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';this iis my importing section.Please tell me if you know code examples

Comment: Where you have used this line getActiveChildNav()? show me

Comment: no havent The library supertabs is calling

Comment: Why I am using this library means it gives me swiping feel to tabs.And it is smooth and good.except this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this once, Maybe this problem occurred not importing properly.

```
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){
    this.navCtrl.getActiveChildNav();
}
```

Just for an suggestion pls try and let me know if any error.

If you provide code sample or some screenshot of an your code.We have clearly understand and help to you.

Comment: I have updated my question withcode.Please check and help me.Whatever is on document I have used.Please refer the link as well